# How to set boolean property value if object id is in another array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays `selectedData` and `allServices`

```
selectedData = [
 { id: 5 },
 { id: 6 }
];

allServices = [
 { id: 3, selected: false },
 { id: 4, selected: false },
 { id: 5, selected: false },
 { id: 6, selected: false },
 { id: 7, selected: false },
];
```

I use the function to compare and change `allServices` structure.

```
const changeStructure = (selectedData, allServices) => {
  selectedData.services.map((_item, index) => {
    allServices.map((value, i) => {
      if (value.id === _item.id) {  
        allServices[i].selected = true;
      } else {
        allServices[i].selected = false;
      }
    }) 
  })
  console.log('final allServices', allServices);
  return allServices;
}
```

console.log `final allServices`  is

```
[
  { id: 3, selected: false },
  { id: 4, selected: false },
  { id: 5, selected: false },
  { id: 6, selected: true },
  { id: 7, selected: false },
];
```

I thought my `allServices` should be

```
[
  { id: 3, selected: false },
  { id: 4, selected: false },
  { id: 5, selected: true },
  { id: 6, selected: true },
  { id: 7, selected: false },
];
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: remove else part in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `else` block from your code, which is updating the previous ids to false on mismatch.

```js
const changeStructure = (selectedData, allServices) => {
  selectedData.services.map((_item, index) => {
    allServices.map((value, i) => {
      if (value.id === _item.id) {  
        allServices[i].selected = true;
      }
    }) 
  })
  console.log('final allServices', allServices);
  return allServices;
}
```

Comment: @Amadan what do you mean by when you say this does not result in the same result ?

Comment: Never mind, I missed that they all _start out_ with `false`. It is inefficient due to not breaking early, but not wrong (except `.services` not existing.)

Comment: @Amadan  yes agree with you on it. I had removed `services` while testing the code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that each time you iterate over your `selectedData` array using the outer `.map()` you're changing all the item ids you previously set to `true` back to `false`. Instead, you should use `.map()` by returning a *new* item each time you iterate. This can be done efficiently by creating a `new Set` of all ids which are in your `selectedData` and changing the `selected` property based on whether the set `.has()` the `id` of the current object:

```js
const selectedData = [ { id: 5 }, { id: 6 } ];
const allServices = [ { id: 3, selected: false }, { id: 4, selected: false }, { id: 5, selected: false }, { id: 6, selected: false }, { id: 7, selected: false } ];

const lut = new Set(selectedData.map(({id}) => id));
const res = allServices.map(obj => ({...obj, selected: lut.has(obj.id)}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

It will only consider the last item in `selectedData` array because every `selected: true` value set is being reset by the `else` block.

Another option is to create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of all the `id`s from `selectedData`. Loop through `allServices` and update the `selected` value based on whether the Set [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) the current object's `id`

```js
const selectedData=[{id:5},{id:6}],
      allServices=[{id:3,selected:false},{id:4,selected:false},{id:5,selected:false},{id:6,selected:false},{id:7,selected:false},];
      
const set = new Set(selectedData.map(o => o.id));
allServices.forEach(o => o.selected = set.has(o.id))

console.log(allServices)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no breaks.  You inspect all possible pairs, and assign to `allServices[i].selected` once for each value in `selectedData`. So `allServices[3].selected` is assigned with `false` and again `false`; `allServices[6].selected` is assigned with `false`, then `true`; but `allServices[5].selected` is assigned with `true`, then overwritten by `false`.

You would want the loops reversed, so that the inner one could be broken out of. Better yet, use `some`.

```
const changeStructure = (selectedData, allServices) => {
  allServices.forEach(value => {
    value.selected = selectedData.some(selected => selected.id == value.id)
  })
  console.log('final allServices', allServices);
  return allServices;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a loop with `allServices` and compare the `id` in each element with the `id` of elements inside `selectedData` using `forEach` function. Like this:

```js
var selectedData = [
 { id: 5 },
 { id: 6 }
];

var allServices = [
 { id: 3, selected: false },
 { id: 4, selected: false },
 { id: 5, selected: false },
 { id: 6, selected: false },
 { id: 7, selected: false },
];

allServices.forEach(x => x.selected = selectedData.find(a => a.id === x.id) !== undefined);

console.log(allServices);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try simple code:

```js
const selectedData = [
 { id: 5 },
 { id: 6 }
];

const allServices = [
 { id: 3, selected: false },
 { id: 4, selected: false },
 { id: 5, selected: false },
 { id: 6, selected: false },
 { id: 7, selected: false }
];

const res = allServices.map(service => ({...service , selected: selectedData.findIndex(selected => selected.id === service.id) >-1 }));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It looks quite simple.

```js
const changeStructure = (selectedData, allServices) => {
    allServices.forEach(item => {
        item.selected = selectedData.some(sel => sel.id === item.id);
    });

    console.log('final allServices', allServices);
    return allServices;
}
```