# How to add object key after comparing two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects.
One array represents list of all countries:

```
const allCountries = [
  {
    name: 'Albania',
    code: 'AL',
    'alpha-3': 'ALB',
    numeric: '8',
  },
  {
    name: 'Algeria',
    code: 'DZ',
    'alpha-3': 'DZA',
    numeric: '12',
  },
  {
    name: 'Andorra',
    code: 'AD',
    'alpha-3': 'AND',
    numeric: '20',
  },
  {
    name: 'Angola',
    code: 'AO',
    'alpha-3': 'AGO',
    numeric: '24',
  },
  {
    name: 'Antigua and Barbuda',
    code: 'AG',
    'alpha-3': 'ATG',
    numeric: '28',
  },
  {
    name: 'Argentina',
    code: 'AR',
    'alpha-3': 'ARG',
    numeric: '32',
  },
];
```

The other array represents list of supported countries:

```
const supportedCountries = [
  {
    name: 'Algeria',
    code: 'DZ',
    'alpha-3': 'DZA',
    numeric: '12',
  },
  {
    name: 'Angola',
    code: 'AO',
    'alpha-3': 'AGO',
    numeric: '24',
  },
  {
    name: 'Argentina',
    code: 'AR',
    'alpha-3': 'ARG',
    numeric: '32',
  },
];
```

What I needed is to create another array of countries with isSupported: true or isSupported: false added to allCountries array to be:

```
[
  {
    name: "Albania",
    code: "AL",
    "alpha-3": "ALB",
    numeric: "8",
    isSupported: false
  },
  {
    name: "Algeria",
    code: "DZ",
    "alpha-3": "DZA",
    numeric: "12",
    isSupported: true
  },
  ... 
];
```

My solution is, and it works fine:

```
const newSet = [];

allCountries.forEach((country) => {
  supportedCountries.forEach((b4b) => {
    if (country.code === b4b.code) {
      newSet.push({ ...country, isSupported: true });
    }
  });
  newSet.push({ ...country, isSupported: false });
});

const uniqueCountries = newSet.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if (!accumulator.find((item) => item.code === current.code)) {
    accumulator.push(current);
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);
```

My question is, what would be the better/cleaner/neater solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set boolean property value if object id is in another array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59485603/how-to-set-boolean-property-value-if-object-id-is-in-another-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` on `allCountries` array. For convenience  `!!` is used to convert result of `find` to boolean.

```js
const allCountries = [
  {
    name: 'Albania',
    code: 'AL',
    'alpha-3': 'ALB',
    numeric: '8',
  },
  {
    name: 'Algeria',
    code: 'DZ',
    'alpha-3': 'DZA',
    numeric: '12',
  },
  {
    name: 'Andorra',
    code: 'AD',
    'alpha-3': 'AND',
    numeric: '20',
  },
  {
    name: 'Angola',
    code: 'AO',
    'alpha-3': 'AGO',
    numeric: '24',
  },
  {
    name: 'Antigua and Barbuda',
    code: 'AG',
    'alpha-3': 'ATG',
    numeric: '28',
  },
  {
    name: 'Argentina',
    code: 'AR',
    'alpha-3': 'ARG',
    numeric: '32',
  },
];

const supportedCountries = [
  {
    name: 'Algeria',
    code: 'DZ',
    'alpha-3': 'DZA',
    numeric: '12',
  },
  {
    name: 'Angola',
    code: 'AO',
    'alpha-3': 'AGO',
    numeric: '24',
  },
  {
    name: 'Argentina',
    code: 'AR',
    'alpha-3': 'ARG',
    numeric: '32',
  },
];
const result = allCountries.map(country => ({
  ...country,
  isSupported: !!supportedCountries.find(item => item.code === country.code),
}));

console.log(result)
```